# Generating a call graph for a php file using Doxygen

Tags: php, doxygen, graphviz, call-graph

I am trying to use doxygen to generate a call graph for a simple php file. My set up is:

```
OS X 10.8.5
Doxygen 1.8.5
graphviz 2.34.0
```

dot is in my path and my doxygen config file looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/XryXdvy0)

When i run doxygen with my config file it generates the html and latex folders but I don't get any graph images whatsoever. Any indications as to what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing specified for INPUT on line 743?
Any errors or warnings? Try adding a warning file on line 731.

Comment: `#2040 HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES` does your code fulfill the conditions mentioned in the commment above this line?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I have a warning file specified. Regarding the input, the current directory is searched if this is not specified. The file i am attempting to generate graphs for is in this directory and other associated documentation is generated successfully for this file.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the file Provided by you as there are two variable to provide the information needed to run DOT Successfully. The First Change is required is

```
# The tag DOT_PATH can be used to specify the path where the dot tool can be 
# found. If left blank, it is assumed the dot tool can be found in the path.

DOT_PATH               =
```

Change it to the dot path location as I did for windows as:

```
DOT_PATH               = "C:/Program Files/Graphviz2.30/bin"
```

This would help Doxygen to run DOT for graphs and 2nd option is to consideration is

```
# The DOT_NUM_THREADS specifies the number of dot invocations doxygen is 
# allowed to run in parallel. When set to 0 (the default) doxygen will 
# base this on the number of processors available in the system. You can set it 
# explicitly to a value larger than 0 to get control over the balance 
# between CPU load and processing speed.

DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
```

Change the 0 to any number to able to generate the graphs. 0 means no thread for creation of graphs. I have changed it as:

```
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 25
```

After changing both things you will have successful Graphs available to your project.

Comment: I have changed DOT_NUM_THREADS to the value indicated. Dot is in my path, so I shouldn't need to specify a value for DOT_PATH if the config comment for this is anything to go by. I have run the config file again and see no graphs in my html folder unfortunately. This is where they should appear correct?

Comment: @BIOS try after giving the path does it generate or not

Comment: Added a path but no change. It's running dot alright as I can see in stdout: 'Running dot...
Running dot for graph 1/1' but i only get some items explaining how any graphs should be interpreted, no graphs for the code itself.

Comment: @BIOS then you must writing document specifications wrongly. Kindly go throgh dozygen manual and then make changes in ur souce code then it will generate graphs. As command ia showing everthibg configured properly error is somewhere else

Comment: What do you mean by 'document specifications' ? The file I'm running the doxyen config on just contains some simple php code without comments so far. I don't see what I should be changing within the code itself?

Comment: @BIOS For PHP kindly use PHPDocumentation not the Doxygen there need some extra things if you want for PHP. Search about that online and you will find that